# Is NAnt still being actively developed?

Tags: nant

Is NAnt still being actively developed, or are there other projects that are gaining more momentum in the Automated Build space?

Edit:
Obviously MSBuild will continue to advance but given all the extra tasks that can be accomplished using NAnt why has development suddenly stopped given that many open source and I assume commercial applications depend on nant.

Comment: Well, judging by the fact that the last release was in December 2007, I don't think so.

Comment: agreed but the latest nighlt build is from 2009-06-21

Comment: Are you missing something in NAnt which cannot be found in neither NAnt nor in NAntContrib?

Comment: nant works fine for my needs at the moment.  but for future projects I will need to consider other options if NAnt is no longer activley developed, especially with VS2010 and .NET 4.0 on the horizon.

Comment: I would be interested if there are alternatives which are as powerfull out of the box (building one's own buildtool with rake or powershell or even using msbuild alone isn't an option, is it?).

Comment: Hadn't even considered building my own. especially when nant does most things that I need right now.  However, if development has stopped on nant then I can see that in time it will fade away to just a memory. As with most applications, nant will need to keep up with the developments within the .net space, or get left behind.  At the moment it seems to be on the verge of being left behind, though still very capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [NAnt Contrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/), but to a reasonable degree, NAnt is one of the rare projects that can be considered "complete" :P

You may also be interested in [Hudson](http://callport.blogspot.com/2009/02/hudson-for-net-projects.html); from the looks of it it can do builds without requiring NAnt (looks like it can do some MSBuild stuff directly, but I haven't used it)

Comment: Hudson is more of a CI server isn't it?  much like cc.net?

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It is an excellent tool and I use it well with Jenkins